# Typescript not allowing to pass props to children with React-notification-component {children?: ReactNode;}

Tags: reactjs, typescript, children, react-notifications-component

I'm using the lib React-notifications-components to create a custom notification. I need to to pass the id from content props to a child component (Notifications) in order to close the notification with onClick event. But when try to do so TypeScript keeps reporting me:
"Property 'id' does not exist on type '{ children?: ReactNode;}"

----------Father-------

```
import { store } from 'react-notifications-component';

  const notification = () => {
    store.addNotification({
      id: 'myId',
      content: p => (
        <Notifications
          handleCloseConfirm={() => store.removeNotification(p.id)}
        />
      ),
      width: 500,
      container: 'bottom-left', // where to position the notifications
      animationIn: ['animated', 'fadeIn'], // animate.css classes that's applied
      animationOut: ['animated', 'fadeOut'], // animate.css classes that's applied
      dismiss: {
        duration: 0,
        // pauseOnHover: true,
        click: false,
        touch: false,
      },
    });
  };

-----------child component----------

import React from 'react';
import { Container, Wrapper } from './styles';
import { Icon } from '../../commons';

interface NotificationsProps {
  handleCloseConfirm: () => void;
}

const Notifications: React.FC<NotificationsProps> = props => {
  const { handleCloseConfirm } = props;

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    handleCloseConfirm();
  };

  return (
    <Container>
      <div>
        <Icon iconName="notifications_success" />
      </div>
      <Wrapper>
        <p>Registro alterado com sucesso</p>
        <Icon iconName="notifications_close" onClick={() => handleSubmit} />
      </Wrapper>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Notifications;
```

Comment: Seems like the problem is with the type of the p variable that is received by the content callback.  Possibly addNotification is a generic function?  I have to look at the docs for this package.

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at the docs and it seems like there's a mistake in the Typescript types.

`content` is defined as a component with takes no props:

```
content?: React.ComponentClass | React.FunctionComponent | React.ReactNode;
```

However the [docs](https://github.com/teodosii/react-notifications-component#options) say that it will receive the `id` as a prop:

> Custom notification content, must be either Class Component, Functional Component or React element. If being supplied as functional or class component, id will be supplied as prop

---

You can get around the error by using `p as any`.

```
handleCloseConfirm={() => store.removeNotification((p as any).id)}
```